# AWS Quicksight Top 10 Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

Question: Is there a way to make a table in AWS QuickSight that only shows 10 entries?

Scenario: User has a table that allows 100 entries to be shown in the table. The user has hundreds of entries; so they have multiple pages to scroll through. The User would like to make that table only show 10 entries; either the highest or lowest value.

Answer (score 3):

Filter type "Top and Bottom" can also be used based on the metric. Please refer to the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkAHH.png)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use the rank formula to rank the data based off the desired metric and then set a filter on the table to show only the ranks 1-10.

Here is a link to the rank function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/rank-function.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below

Under the Filter Tab

1. Create a new filter by selecting the field you want to filter.
2. A new filter will be created. Then click the **edit** option
3. Go to **filter type** where you will see a few pre-built filter
   options, including Top N and Botton N

That should solve your problem.